# Is reflection still inefficient on contemporary JDKs(11+)?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm looking to avoid having a ridiculously large switch statement, so instead I've created this method:

```
private static Map<String, Constructor<?>> constructorCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();    
public static Object instantiate(String path, Object... params) {
    
    try {
        Constructor<?> cons = null;
        
        if(constructorCache.containsKey(path)) {
            cons = constructorCache.get(path);
        }
        else {
            Class<?>[]clazzes = new Class<?>[params.length];
            
            for(int a = 0; a != params.length; a++) 
                clazzes[a] = params[a].getClass();
            
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(path);
            cons = clazz.getConstructor(clazzes);
        }
            
        
        return cons.newInstance(params);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while instantiating " + path + " Stacktrace: " + e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Is this bad practice, especially for performance-critical code?

Comment: Reflection is bad because Java is a statically typed language, and by eschewing any help you would otherwise get from the compiler, you are opening yourself up to a world of bugs. Performance has not been a relevant concern WRT reflection for at least 10 years. The problem is correctness.

Comment: @Michael Actually reflection does hurt performance.  It’s a lot harder for the JIT compiler to optimize reflection.  That said, your first sentence is right.  Evan, whatever you’re trying to do, there is almost certainly a better way to do it that doesn’t involve reflection;  but without more knowledge of your goal, it’s hard to recommend anything.

Comment: The goal was to resolve an object from a string of its name. I ended up just doing a method that returns <T extends A>, where A is an abstract class. Inside is a large switch statement that casts the appropriate result to T.